# Sending self classes Tkinter Entry data to a function outside of its scope

Tags: class, function, python-3.x, scope, tkinter

I have setup two entry boxes, and the goal is to press a button and apply some type of math to the input numbers using a function outside of the scope. (I have left out the packing and framing code since I don't think it is relative to the problem.)

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry1= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)
        self.entry2= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)

        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command = self.doMathFunction)

def doMathFunction():
    #what do I put here that allows me to either run a .get on self.entry1 and 2
```

I thought about making the entries global in scope, but that will prevent me from running a get on them? I think there is a way to have an event run a get when the enduser puts in numbers into the Entry box, since it is mentioned in the ktinker documentation as "needing more explanation." I am not really sure what the best way of doing this is, and my research comes back with conflicting answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have your button call a method on the class, and have that method call `doMathFUnction`, passing it the values. Doing it this way means that your `doMathFunc` function doesn't need to know anything about the inner workings of the GUI.

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(..., command=self.doCalc)

    def doCalc(self):
        a = self.entry1.get()
        b = self.entty2.get()
        doMathFunction(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If doMathFunction **has** to be out of scope, you can use a lambda statement and add variables to your doMathFunction.

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry1= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)
        self.entry2= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)

        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command = \
             lambda e1 = self.entry1.get(), e2 = self.entry2.get(): doMathFunction(e1,e2))

def doMathFunction(e1, e2):
    print(e1*e2) # Or whatever you were going to do
```

Normally, using a function in a command statement acts like a variable declaration, the function is executed and the return statement is assigned to the variable. However, with lambda, the function behind it is only executed on-call.

So when calcButton gets pushed and calls its command statement, the lambda "function" (with e1 and e2) is executed. It's like creating a middleman function to handle the call.

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry1= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)
        self.entry2= tkinter.Entry(self.uframe, width=10)

        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(..., command = self.middleman)

    def middleman(self):
        e1 = self.entry1.get()
        e2 = self.entry2.get()
        doMathFunction(e1, e2)

def doMathFunction(e1, e2):
    print(e1*e2) # Or whatever you were going to do
```